# NET Core API not able to change the log verbose level

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have an Web App API deployed in Azure, I am able to view the logs level ERROR, but I am not able to view the logs Level Information. My application is deployed in a linux Docker container. I find out that we are able to change the verbose level, but I don't have this configuration available in my portal, I set Application Logging to File System.

[image]

When testing locally I can view the logs, but in Azure I am not able.

I added manually this configuration to my AppSettings :Logging_LogLevel_Default Value : Information, as I wasn't able to find out the configuration which was suposed to be uploaded from my appsettings.json configuration file, see below :

"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
"Default": "Information",
"ImageProducer": "Information",
"Microsoft": "None",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore": "None",
"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "None",
"Application Insights Telemetry": "None"
}
},

I checked my environment variable using Kudu, but I couldn't find anything related to this logging configuration.

In the ConfigureServices at the Startup, I injected the ILogger, because the two classes below injected to access the FileShare or FileSystem uses the ILogger injected. If I don't do it, I get a compiler error.

```
                        // Added as FileShare and FileSystem Classes has ILogger into the constructor. Otherwise an error happens.
        var serviceProvider = BuildTheProvider(services); 
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<ApplicationLogs>>();
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger), logger);

        // Inject the correct class, according the configuration, development uses
        if (Configuration.GetValue<bool>("ApplicationSettings:UseDevelopmentStorage"))
        {
            services.AddScoped<IFileShare, FileSystem>();
        }
        else
        {
            services.AddScoped<IFileShare, StorageLibrary.Repositories.FileShare>();
        }

        // Setup Swagger Document
        SetupSwaggerDocument(services);
```

In the API controller. I inject the Logger.

```
        public DocumentUploaderController(IStorage storage,
                            IQueue queue,
                            IFileShare fileShare,
                            ILogger<DocumentUploaderController> logger,
                            IConfiguration configuration)
```

In the controller method I use the injected logger.

```
_logger.LogInformation(LoggingEvents.InsertItem, $"POST : Starting upload document.");
```

Comment: hello Ricardo. Can you pass on more details or coded examples? So we can help better... and if you are using .NET, configure Serilog to expose your logs

Comment: hello, I added the code. I will check out the Serilog.